# Given embedding vector A and vector B, how to find top k embedding vectors such that they are similar to vector A and dissimilar to vector B

Tags: machine-learning, word-embedding, word2vec, cosine-similarity

Which would be better approach for getting top k embedding vectors such that they are similar to embedding vector A and dissimilar to vector B.

**Approach 1:**

- calculate `f(V) = cosine_similarity(A,V) - cosine_similarity(B,V)` for each vector V
- sort vectors by f(V) value in descending order
- take first k of them.

**Approach 2:**

- calculate
  `f(V) = cosine_similarity(A,V)` , `g(V) = cosine_similarity(B,V)`
  for each vector V
- sort vectors by f(V) value in descending order
- take first k of them
- sort selected k vectors by g(V) in ascending order.

**Approach 3:**

- calculate `f(V) = cosine_similarity((A - B),V)` for each vector V
- sort vectors by f(V) value in descending order
- take first k of them.

Also, suggest better approach if you have other than above two.

Note: embedding vector was calculated using word2vec algorithm

Answer (score 0):

As the objective is to find the most similar to A and disimilar Vector to B approach 2 would be the most appropriate.

Why not Approach 1:
It can lead to confusing results. If you look at the example below multiple scenarios lead to same final value. This may lead to few problems :

1. For same output how do you know which vector should be preferred
2. Subtracting with each other may cancel out impact of dissimilarity on one with other

[image]

Why not Approach 3:
Vector Subtraction is not ***commutative***. So you will get different results based on whether you use A first or B first. Moreover lets see an example where it fails completely :

Suppose we have 2 dimension vector A and B, and we want to vector V which is

A = 6,0
B = 0.01,-0.01

V = 3,-1

Cos(A,V) = 0.94
Cos(B,V) = 0.894
Cos(A-B,V) = 0.94

Second Secnario:
A = 6,0
B = -0.01,0.01

V = 3,-1

Cos(A,V) = 0.94
Cos(B,V) = -0.894
Cos(A-B) = 0.94

Though cos A and cos B are two extremes in scenario 1 and scenario 2. Cos(A-B) gives the same result. Hence i will not advice to use Cos(A-B)

Approach 2 will work expected in your case.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a heuristic, but how about `f(V) = cosine_similarity(A,V) * min(1, 1 - cosine_similarity(B,V))`? I'm applying the `min` here so that the multiplier won't get larger than one. Up to you whether you want to include it or not.

This could be tuned further as `f(V) = max(0, cosine_similarity(A,V))^a * min(1, 1 - cosine_similarity(B,V))^b`, but you'd need to experiment to see which values of `a` and `b` works the best for you.